# AJAX return undefined in html document

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<result searchKeyword="Mathematics">

  <video>
    <title>Chaos Game</title>
    <channel>Numberphile</channel>
    <view>428K</view>
    <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs</link> 
    <image>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/kbKtFN71Lfs/0.jpg</image> 
    <length>8:38</length>
  </video> 

  <video>
    <title>Australian Story: Meet Eddie Woo, the maths teacher you wish you&apos;d had in high school</title>
    <channel>ABC News (Australia)</channel>
    <view>223K</view>
    <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjIHB8WzJek</link> 
    <image>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/SjIHB8WzJek/0.jpg</image> 
    <length>28:08</length>
  </video> 

  <video>
    <title>Ham Sandwich Problem</title>
    <channel>Numberphile</channel>
    <view>557K</view>
    <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCXmUi56rao</link> 
    <image>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCXmUi56rao/0.jpg</image> 
    <length>5:53</length>
  </video> 

  <video>
    <title>Magic Square Party Trick</title>
    <channel>Numberphile</channel>
    <view>312K</view>
    <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko</link> 
    <image>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aQxCnmhqZko/0.jpg</image> 
    <length>3:57</length>
  </video> 

  <video>
    <title>The 8 Queen Problem</title>
    <channel>Numberphile</channel>
    <view>909K</view>
    <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPcBU0Z2Hj8</link> 
    <image>http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jPcBU0Z2Hj8/0.jpg</image> 
    <length>7:03</length>
  </video> 

</result>
```

I have created this html file which has an AJAX call to get the xml file but it return all the values as "undefined"

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A7-Question2</title>

    <script>
        function getSearch()
        {
            // create an XMLHttpRequest
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //create a handler for the readyState change
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp);
            };

          //get XML file by making async call
          xhttp.open("GET", "A7.xml", true);
          xhttp.send();
        }

        // handler for the readyState change
        function readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp){
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4){
            // readyState = 4 means DONE

            if(xhttp.status == 200){
              // status = 200 means OK

              handleStatusSuccess(xhttp);
            }else{
              // status is NOT OK

              handleStatusFailure(xhttp);
            }
          }
        }

        // XMLHttpRequest failed
        function handleStatusFailure(xhttp){

          // display error message

          var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");

          displayDiv.innerHTML = "XMLHttpRequest failed: status " + xhttp.status;
        }

        // XMLHttpRequest success
        function handleStatusSuccess(xhttp){

          var xml = xhttp.responseXML;

          // print XML on the console
          console.log(xml);

          // parse the XML into an object
          var searchResult = parseXML(xml);

          // print object on the console
          console.log(searchResult);

          // display the object on the page
          display(searchResult);
        }

        // parse the XML into an object
        function parseXML(xml){

         var resultElement = xml.getElementsByTagName("result")[0];

         //create a receipt object to hold the information in the xml file
         var searchResult = {};
         searchResult.searchKeyword= resultElement.getAttribute("searchKeyword");

         var videoElements = xml.getElementsByTagName("video");

         //create an array to hold the items
         searchResult.videoArray = [];

         for(var i=0; i< videoElements.length; i++){
             var video = {};
             video.title = videoElements[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
             video.channel = Number(videoElements[i].getElementsByTagName("channel")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
             video.view = Number(videoElements[i].getElementsByTagName("view")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
             video.link = Number(videoElements[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
             video.image = Number(videoElements[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
             searchResult.videoArray.push(video);
        };
          return searchResult;
        }

        // display the searcg result object on the page
        function display(searchResult){

            var html = "<p>searchKeyword: Mathematics</p>";
            for(var i=0; i<searchResult.videoArray.length; i++){
            var video = searchResult.videoArray[i];
            html += "title: " + searchResult.title + "<br/>";
            html += "channel: " + searchResult.channel + "<br/>";
            html += "view: " +  searchResult.view + "<br/>";
            html += "link: " +  searchResult.link + "<br/>";
            html += "image: " +  searchResult.image + "<br/>";
            html += "length: " +  searchResult.length + "<br/>";
            }

            var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");

            displayDiv.innerHTML = html;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getSearch()">Get Search Result</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the problem with my success function? Is it returning null because it hasn't returned all the values or something due to how AJAX runs?

Thanks heaps for any help

Comment: What is returned from your `console.log(xml)`? Is that `undefined` as well or does it bring back a string?

Comment: are you stating that `xhttp.responseXML` is null? what is `xhttp.response` and `xhttp.responseText`? What can you see in the browser developer tools network tab for the response for that request? What browser are you using? Is your page being served using `http:`, `https:` or `file:`? Are there any errors/warnings in the browser developer tools console?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code to go over and a working snippet can't be produced because we can't put the XML file here.

This answer is making an assumption that your response from the `XMLHttpRequest` is null and the problem does not lie in any of your parsing functions.

It also seems that you're over complicating the request process by passing it around to many functions when it's quite simple itself.

Here is an example I made locally that correctly logged the XML to the console:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A7-Questions2</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

                var xml = xhttp.responseXML;

                // Logs just fine for me. You can do your parsing here.
                console.log(xml);

            }

        };

        xhttp.onerror = function() {

            // Display error message.
            var displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');

            displayDiv.textContent = 'XMLHttpRequest failed status: ' + xhttp.status;

        };

        xhttp.open('GET', './path/to/xml.xml');
        xhttp.send();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```